# How to make partly transparent png-image buttons for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, macos, transparent

My iPhone App has custom buttons that display png-images.
 I like to replace the white color in those images by a transparent color. Is there a tool on the Mac that allows me to do that? (or is there some other way to indicate which color is transparent in xcode?)

Comment: This is easy to do in photoshop (use Replace Color or just add a new layer and multiply).

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have photoshop...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Preview application has a mode on its select tool called "Instant Alpha" which eases selection of backgrounds.  Once you have your background selected, you can simply press the "Delete" key and that area of the image will be removed.  Save it as a PNG with the "Alpha" box checked and you're done.

Most other image editing tools, particularly those supporting multiple layers in the image, will also properly support PNG alpha channels.  These will likely be easier than using Preview, but they are all third-party and many cost money so you will need to make that decision.

Please note however that if you are starting from an image with a solid background to which some things have a faded edge that blends in to the background, it is unlikely that you'll be able to remove the background entirely to your satisfaction without cutting in to the actual image.

You may have seen GIF images in the past which were designed to blend in on a white background and had some bright pixels at the edges which stood out and look ugly on darker backgrounds.  An image properly saved as PNG or any other format with an alpha channel from the beginning will not have this problem.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that the Preview application had that functionality! I will try to avoid those white pixels..

Answer (score 3):

Just set the image view alpha.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor]; //Set background color

  UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images-4.jpeg"]] ; // Create and initialize imageView 
  imgView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 200,250);// Set frame for imageView
  [self.view addSubview:imgView];
  imgView.alpha=0.1; //Adjust alpha
}
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Start with a png file (use image preview).

You have to go to View > Show Edit Toolbar.

Then widen the window so that you can see all of the icons.

Then click the icon that looks like a magic wand.

And then click and drag on the color you want to erase.